# TS remote application edit settings through command line

Tags: terminal-server

The title may be misleading but what I am trying to do is change the existing settings for the rdp file that users will use when clicking on the ts web access page.

We have a lot of clients on this virtualized remote app system and I would like to modify our code to update the setting so it happens for all machines at the same time, once they run our update.

The app is running on server 2008 and the system already exists and is being used in production.
I need to change the rdp setting for span monitors:i:0. The default is span monitors:i:1
This causes some of our screens to span the monitor or be impossible to get to if the user has more than 1 monitor on their local machine.

I have tried changing this setting manually and it is working great but we need a way to do it through code. I was thinking that there is a cmd line interface for this but I dont know what it is. I looked at mstsc but that doesnt seem to have what I need.

If there is a cmd line interface then I can make an exe that sets it in code. Unless you can think of another way.